# QTableWidget resize column both on content and stretch

Tags: c++, qt

So, with

```
 tableWibget->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

my column are resized to content, but that doesn't look good when content is small and grid doesn't fit all the space.

and with

```
tableWibget->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

it fits all the space, but sometimes content of some cell doesn't shown fully.

how can I make something like both above - content must fit all the place in widget, but if some cell can't take all content it resize to fit it all and scroll bar appears

Answer (score 1):

You can set resize mode on column index as below::

```
headerView->SetResizeMode(0, QHeaderview::Stretch);

headerView->SetResizeMode(1,QHeaderview::Interactive);
```